# Design Patterns for Asynchronous Apex

Tags: apex, asynchronous, libraries

**Background**

After listening to Dan Appleman's talk:

- [Dreamforce 13: Design Patterns for Asynchronous Apex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqqiIg_mynY)

I went to look at the code:

- [Sample Code: Design Patterns for Asynchronous Apex](http://advancedapex.com/dreamforce13/)

Unfortunately, the code isn't production ready.

**Question**

Are there any similar Asynchronous Apex libraries which are tested and reliable  out there?

Comment: What ones in particular are concerned about? I'd be more worried about the fact that this is five years old and somewhat outdated.

Comment: @sfdcfox I am getting this error `Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a batch start, batch execute, or future method.` so was going to use Dan Applemans `Replace future calls with custom async request object' pattern. Unless you have a better more modern approach I could use?

Comment: Pretty sure this presentation is pre-Queueable (didn't watch the whole thing), which has quite a few benefits over normal future, but you might still otherwise adopt the custom object approach, so that failures can be retried layer. I'd think something more like queueable + schedulable for better performance. I think you'd be better off asking a question about the problem you're having, and solutions you're exploring, rather than going off on this tangent. This is the so-called [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox I was just looking at `Queueable` and wondering if it is the way to go... But I am concerned about getting this error `Too many queueable jobs added to the queue: 2` so I might use a this library [apex-async](https://github.com/redteal/apex-async), thoughts?

Comment: Yes, if you have need better monitoring of your asynchronous calls, using the custom object approach is still viable. In fact, I once implemented a persistent asynchronous call out mechanism myself some years ago that involved a complicated scheduler, batchable (again, queueable didn't exist yet), and a custom object to track calls until they were successful.

Comment: @sfdcfox I don't actually need to monitor the async jobs. But I do want to avoid both `Too many queueable jobs added to the queue: 2` and `Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a batch start, batch execute, or future method.` errors. After reading the `Queueable` documentation, I'd like to confirm how `Too many queueable jobs added to the queue: 2` occurs if a transaction can queue 50 items and chaining is allowed?

Comment: You're still only allowed one in asynchronous mode. The problem is, there is no silver bullet to solving the problem. Every time you reach a governor limit, you need to think about why you're there, and then figure out how to restructure. Libraries are great and all, but they don't solve problems. Analysis of the problem solves problems. You need to think about it, figure out a better way. If there was single solution that always worked, we wouldn't have anything left to solve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86101/discussion-between-robs-and-sfdcfox).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dan Appleman Dreamforce session in 2013 is quite out of date.

These days (2018) you would want to use `Queueable` inteface.

Read more here:

- [Salesforce Developers Blog: Queueable Apex: More Than an @future](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/05/queueable-apex-future.html)
- [Apex Developer Guide: Queueable Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Queueable.htm)

---

But as a direct response to the question, there is a library:

- [Github: apex-async](https://github.com/redteal/apex-async)

This is a more mature and production ready library / wrapper for `Queueable` and  `Schedulable` that's worth a look.

**Example use**

```
public class FooAsyncTask implements RT_IAsyncTask {
    public void execute(AsyncRequest__c asyncRequest, Map<String, Object> params) {
        System.debug(params.get('i'));
    }
}
```

Insertion of `AsyncRequest__c` triggers the task to be queued for processing.

```
List<AsyncRequest__c> reqs = new List<AsyncRequest__c>();
for (Integer i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object> {'i' => i};
    reqs.add(RT_AsyncRequestService.create(FooAsyncTask.class, params));
}
insert reqs;
```

An abstraction for asynchronous Apex implementations in Salesforce:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

That Dreamforce talk is hopelessly out of date - 2013!
I haven't looked closely at the apex-async library, but it certainly uses at least some of the design patterns I cover in my Advanced Apex book.
The fourth edition was recently published and includes considerably more detail along with coverage of platform events. See http://advancedapex.com

Comment: 0

What are the advantages of inserting every job, instead of just the failed one's in this design pattern ? Why can't we fire the job immediately instead of inserting into asynrequest__c and insert only if it fails for reprocessing ?

Comment: Because there are certain kinds of errors - system errors and CPU timeout errors, that aren't trappable.